# Issue with custom blender addon: upgrade to 2.8x required

Tags: python, blender

I made a custom export addon and added it into Blender. When I used it for the first time, it worked perfectly, no errors. However, when I close the program and start it up again, the addon said 'upgrade to 2.8x required' and I couldn't use it. I knew this meant that some code in the addon was outdated, but like I said, it worked with no errors before. What's happening, how can I fix it? By the way, I used the built-in export template, so I don't think the code is the problem